# Почему NUXT/VUE.js не может вывести конечный элемент json из VUEX

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

У меня есть вот такой JSON

```
{"user":{"name":"Алексей","surname":"Тихонравов","age":"25","incapacitated":"Инвалид 2 группы","address":"г. Самара, ул. Парфирьева, 19, кв. 22","gender":"male"},"allergy":[{"item":"Ампицилин"},{"item":"кошки"},{"item":"домашняя"},{"item":"пыль"},{"item":"животные"}],"vaccinations":[{"item":"Дифтерия"},{"item":"столбняк"},{"item":"коклюш"},{"item":"гемофильная палочка типа Б"},{"item":"полеомелит"},{"item":"корь"},{"item":"краснуха"},{"item":"ветряная оспа"},{"item":"гепатит Б"}],"diagnoses":[{"item":"Неспецифический язвенный колит"},{"item":"муковисцидоз"},{"item":"Болезнь Вильсона-Коновалова"},{"item":"Анкилозирующий спондилоартрит"},{"item":"Волчанка"},{"item":"корь"},{"item":"краснуха"},{"item":"ветряная оспа"},{"item":"гепатит Б"}],"timing":{"Гастроэнтеролог Иванова А.А.":{"hospital":"Самарская городская поликлиника № 3, ул. Мичурина, 6а","date":"22.03.21","time":"12:30"},"Анализ крови на сахар":{"hospital":"Самарская городская поликлиника № 3, ул. Мичурина, 6а","date":"22.03.21","time":"16:00"},"Процедура 2":{"hospital":"Самарская городская поликлиника № 3, ул. Мичурина, 6а","date":"22.03.21","time":"16:30"}},"books":{"Жалоба на здоровье 124":{"date":"22.03.21","time":"12:30"},"Жалоба на здоровье 154":{"date":"22.03.21","time":"12:30"}},"medicines":{"Кровалол":{"count":"1 раз в день"},"Метронидазол":{"count":"3 раза в день"},"Инфлексимаб":{"count":"1 раз в день до 26.08.2022"}}}
```

Мой store/index.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И scripts моего компонента:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытаюсь делать интерполяцию {{ USERS.user }} - все работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда пытаюсь вывести {{ USERS.user.name }} то уже выдает ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем что если я начаю добавлять компоненту v-for="item in USERS.user" и внутри выводить {{ USERS.user.name }} - то все работает, но мне так не подходит.

Всю голову уже сломал, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: А что выводит `{{item}}

Comment: @Node_pro Если я делаю так: <BaseH1 v-for="item in USERS.user"  class="blue visual-name-content__title"> 
      {{ item }}
      </BaseH1> То выводит свойста каждого элемента в USERS.user - тоесть name, surmane , age и тп